# How to Search Values in all table in a mysql database?

Tags: php

How i find the Last Updated Values inside the all the table field in a given Database?
Search results for "%2015-07-08%" at least one of the words:

Answer (score 1):

Its not impossible, but its not trivial either. I don't think that there is an easy way to do this with SQL alone (I assume that you use mySQL, but you haven't really specified what kind of database you are using).

One way to do it is make a script that uses INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables to find the relevant tables and columns to search through, then iterate those in PHP and execute queries that search those columns and tables.

Edit: 
Just for the sake of doing it I made a small example of what i mean, this code uses PDO:

```
function findAll($search_str, $database, $types = ['tinytext','blob','varchar','text','longblob']){
    global $pdo;

    foreach($types as &$t){
        $t = "'" . $t . "'";
    }
    $types = implode(',',$types);

    $s = $pdo->prepare("
      SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
      WHERE 
        TABLE_SCHEMA = :database
        AND DATA_TYPE IN ($types)
    ");
    $s->bindValue(':database', $database);
    $s->execute();
    $results = [];

    foreach($s->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $column){
        $search = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $database.${column['TABLE_NAME']} WHERE ${column['COLUMN_NAME']} LIKE :search_str");
        $search->bindValue(':search_str', $search_str);
        $search->execute();

        $result = $search->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(count($result))
            $results[$column['TABLE_NAME']] = isset($results[$column['TABLE_NAME']])
                ? array_merge(
                    $results[$column['TABLE_NAME']],
                    $result
                )
                : $result;

    }
    return $results;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
findAll('%foobar%','my_database');

findAll('%2015-07-08%','my_database',['date','datetime','timestamp']); //Only search date types...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about checking the latest value of the key column e.g. in an column with auto increment you check the highest value? This is just a suggestion though while assuming you have such a column. The other idea would be to add a column with a timestamp data type so that you can update it automatically during inserts or updates.